# awk in bash not working

Tags: bash, awk

Code below  is the simple version, but also illustrates the problem.

Version **does not** work:

```
df | awk -f <(cat - <<-'EOD'
{
    if(                                                                                                                                                                                       
        $1 == "tmpfs" ) {
            print $0;
        }
}
EOD
)
```

Version **does** work:

```
df | awk -f <(cat - <<-'EOD'
{
    if( $1 == "tmpfs" ) {                                                                                                                                                                     
            print $0;
        }
}
EOD
)
```

the difference is how I place condition with if, the same line (works) or different lines (not working).
The production version has four long conditions, So I have to place them on different lines to make the code more readable. Any one have came into this?

Comment: Does this behave differently if you don't use a process substitution?

Comment: Did you consider trying an awk script without the pipe from df and the process substitution and the here document with the UUOC? All of that is obfuscating the issue - just a simple awk script with a BEGIN section would have captured and highlighted your problem.

Comment: The first version still does not work when if-conditon spans multiple lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use escapes for end of line for your long `if` statement:

```
df | awk -f <(cat - <<-'EOD'
{
    if ( \
        $1 == "tmpfs" ) {
            print $0;
        }
}
EOD
)
```

`awk` syntax evidently expects the `if` statement/expression to be on a single line. In Unix/Linux it's common to be able to use the backslash () as a line continuation character. So it will treat the above `if ( \` and the following line as if they were all on the same line syntactically.

Comment: Could you explain me what behind the scene? This works but why does not work when on different lines?

Comment: `awk` evidently expects the `if` statement to be on a single "line". The escape is used frequently in Linux (Unix) as a "line continuation" character.

Comment: Any reference or docs on `evidently expects the if statement to be on a single "line"`?

Comment: @schemacs the only thing I found quickly related to this behavior is here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Statements_002fLines.html, where it states: *`awk` is a line-oriented language. Each rule's action has to begin on the same line as the pattern. To have the pattern and action on separate lines, you must use backslash continuation; there is no other option.*.

Comment: Yes, line-oriented, no other option. Thanks for your quick answer to my question.

Comment: You seem to be right; each term of an if needs to be on a single line.  However, this works: `df | awk -f <(cat - <<-'EOD'` — `{` — `if( $1 == "tmpfs" &&` — `$2 == "squeegee") {` — `print $0;` — `}` — `}` (where the long dashes '—' represent newlines). At least, it is OK for Mac OS X version of `awk` and GNU `awk`.  So, 4 long conditions can be written on 4 lines with no more than `&&` or `||` separating them.  But the conditions must be complete; you can't go breaking the lines around an `==` operator, for example.
EOD

Comment: The pattern/action reference is about awk's `<pattern>{<action>}` syntax and has nothing to do with the issue seen here with an `if` statement. The relevant section of the gawk manual is `Most often, each line in an awk program is a separate statement or separate rule...However, gawk ignores newlines after any of the following symbols and keywords: ,    {    ?    :    ||    &&    do    else`. As you can see `(` is not one of those symbols.

Comment: Oh, and wrt `Just use escapes for end of line for your long if statement` - no, just don't do that as it makes your code harder to read! What's the point in all that UUOC and here doc complexity anyway?

Comment: @EdMorton, I agree that's the context, but the beginning of the statement on that page says, "`awk` is a line-oriented language." I think that's a pretty strong clue. I just couldn't find a better reference. And the reference you are citing I'm not sure is any stronger by itself, but certainly supports. Regarding code readability, the OP pointed out they have an EXCESSIVELY long `if` condition. I would think the escape of a new line would make it more readable in that case. That's why I say "just use escape" in that case.

Comment: @mrbatch the reference you quoted is 100% only about the very specific `<pattern>{<action>}` syntax and is completely unrelated to `if` statements or anything else in the language. It's explaining why you must have the `{<action>}` start on the same line as the `<pattern>`, a common rookie mistake. Fair enough wrt escaping if the condition is very long, I guess I could see that. I can't imagine why the OP is using process substitution with cat and a here doc in the first place though, and the `if` isn't necessary at all in the posted example.

Answer (score 3):

@mbratch answered your question, but as an aside, your posted script:

```
df | awk -f <(cat - <<-'EOD'
{
    if( \
        $1 == "tmpfs" ) {
            print $0;
        }
    }
EOD
)
```

can/should be written as just this:

```
df | awk '$1 == "tmpfs"'
```

If you tell us what you're trying to do, we could probably help more.

Comment: As I said, this code is simplified, and the code in production is much more complex than this.